# Barcode printer and SAAS

Tags: php, web-applications, printing, barcode, saas

My company recently developed a small file management web app for a law firm. And we have a problem. The application was supposed to be deployed on their own internal server. But now, they want us to host it. That wouldn't be a problem if we were not using a small .bat script, launched with PHP's exec() function, for barcode printing. The printer needs some specific format instructions, and we need the printing to be done silently.

So here's my question : is there a way to print on this device from our application ? The main problem is that our boss wants to have **nothing** installed on their server, not even a minimal C# app or something I could have used to listen to calls from the main web app. I guess the solution must be on the client side. Javascript ? A Java applet ?

Thanks for your answers, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: "The printer needs some specific format instructions" you should specify what instructions and how they are passed to printer? via serial port? usb?

Comment: The printer is connected to the server via USB, and I really couldn't say much more about the instructions. I didn't work on that part of the project. My coworker who did is sick, so I'm the one who has to find a solution. I love my job !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of printer you're using but I know Dymo has a nice SDK which will let your print from the web using javascript. I use it for addresses within my contact manager (little PHP/MySQL thinger.) Select contact, click button, label pops out. Some other fella is using the same idea for a wine cataloging system where it prints production information to a label for the bottles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We probably should have looked into that before buying the device. I'll search a bit if there's a similar SDK for Zebra printers, but my hopes aren't high.

Comment: The good news is the Dymo brand printers are pretty cheap. Connecting local devices to web applications is a pure pain-in-the-code — I can understand your pain!

Comment: That's good news indeed, thanks again ! I'll update the question with the solution when it will be decided.